# Can't get to deserialize XML in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, msxml

I am trying, from a VBA for Excel program, to query a RESTful API, in VB.NET.

However, I can't seem to deserialize the XML properly.

On the VBA side, the code is the following:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "http://localhost:50261/api/values"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0;Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/xml"
objHTTP.send ("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><KPISheet><site>mysite</site><unit>myunit</unit></KPISheet>)")
```

As you can see, I am sending what I believe is a well formed and very simple XML document.

On VB.NET side, I have a class, called KPISheet:

```
Public Class KPISheet
    Public Site As String
    Public Unit As String
End Class
```

And a WebAPI, to get the 'POST':

```
Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody> oKPISheet As KPISheet)
    Debug.Print("toto")
End Sub
```

If I set a breakpoint in the Debug line, I can see that oKPISheet is Nothing, the XML file is not deserialized.

In the Output window, I get the following Error Message:

*Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll*

I have tried with and without the  tag, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I ended up changed my load to JSON, and thats work like a charm...

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see, I am sending what I believe is a well formed and very simple XML document.

Unfortunately your assumption is wrong:

```
<KPISheet>site>mysite</site>
```

That's invalid XML. You are missing an opening `<` for the site tag. You also seem to have some closing `)` as last character in your XML.

So you can try sending valid XML:

```
objHTTP.send("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><KPISheet><site>mysite</site><unit>myunit</unit></KPISheet>")
```

Also notice that the correct content type should be `text/xml` and not `application/xml`:

```
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "text/xml"
```

Also bear in mind that XML is case sensitive, so you should capitalize your tag names to match your property names:

```
objHTTP.send("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><KPISheet><Site>mysite</Site><Unit>myunit</Unit></KPISheet>")
```

and last but not least, Web API uses the datacontract serializer by default for working with XML, so you need to include namespaces:

```
objHTTP.send("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><KPISheet xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApplication1.ViewModels.KPISheet""><Site>mysite</Site><Unit>myunit</Unit></KPISheet>")
```

Don't forget to adjust the namespace to match your `KPISheet` class.

Alternatively if you don't want to include namespaces you could switch the XML serializer being used:

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

And if you want to keep using the data contract serializer you could decorate your view model with the corresponding attributes:

```
<DataContract(Namespace="")>
Public Class KPISheet
    <DataMember>
    Public Site As String
    <DataMember>
    Public Unit As String
End Class
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's just an issue with the copy/paste :(
The VBA code is alright

Comment: See my update about the case sensitivity of XML and the need to include the namespace.